# Regular Expression to match two similar word

Tags: javascript, regex

I run into a problem where the regular expression won't match two similar words:

#### Example:

```
bitcoin and bitcoin atm
```

#### Regular Expression:

```
new RegExp("(?:^|\\b)(bitcoin|bitcoin atm|test bitcoin)(?!\\w)");
```

#### Here's a demo :

```js
(function myFunction() {

    var str = "bitcoin and bitcoin atm and test and test a and new test";
    
    var patt = new RegExp("(?:^|\\b)(bitcoin|bitcoin atm|test|test a|new test)(?!\\w)", "g");
    
    var res = str.match(patt);
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    
})()
```

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Because it's matching `"bitcoin"` first inside `"bitcoin atm"`.

Comment: Reorder your regex to have specific queries first (*ie. `"bitcoin atm"` before `"bitcoin"`*)

Comment: I know that's one way, but it's not a ultimate solution because I sort my data by name and bitcoin will always be in front of bitcoin atm.

Comment: @JackGuo: there is no other way or "ultimate solution", sort the words in a reverse order and join them. As an aside, you should read about word boundaries to well understand how it works.

Comment: Take a look at [How a Regex Engine Works Internally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)

Comment: So sort your values by length first 
var patterns = ['bitcoin', 'bitcoin atm','test', 'test a', 'new text'];
patterns.sort(function(a,b){return b.length - a.length})
var patt = new RegExp("(?:^|\\b)(" + patterns.join('|') + ")(?!\\w)", "g");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move more specific matches to be higher priority in your matching pattern.

```js
(function myFunction() {

    var str = "bitcoin and bitcoin atm and test and test a and new test";

    var patterns = ['bitcoin', 'bitcoin atm','test', 'test a', 'new text'];

    patterns.sort(function(a,b){return b.length - a.length})
    
    var patt = new RegExp("(?:^|\\b)(" + patterns.join('|') + ")(?!\\w)", "g");
    
    var res = str.match(patt);
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    
})()
```

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: That's quick fix but I can't use it in my project because I'll pass in an array that's sorted by name and bitcoin will always be at the top.

Comment: @JackGuo I edited to show how you can sort your array by length to get more specific matches first (its dumb but simple, make it more complex if you need to)

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate your help :)